# How to process float32 arrays by video compression tools and get back float32 values? Video and image formats which natively supports float32 values

Tags: linux, bash, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-compression

I have multiple arrays of float32 values, which might be interpreted as images. They go in the sequence. They are one channel only and they don't restrict itself to [0,1] range.

I would like to process them by `ffmpeg` and create compressed video out of them. Then I want to decompress them to the sequence of images, or possibly also raw array of float values.

Let's say I have `RAWARRAYSFILE` of float32 of frames with given dimensions and I want to convert it to the video. In ffmpeg there is a `pix_fmt gray32le` and I can convert my raw files into the video using e.g.

```
DIMX=3250
DIMY=2132
dd if=$RAWARRAYSFILE |  ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -f rawvideo -s "${DIMX}x${DIMY}" -pix_fmt grayf32le  -i - vid.mp4
```

Now to get the sequence of the images back, I can

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -pix_fmt grayf32le out/processed%05d.tif
```

However not the `vid.mp4` video nor `out/processed%05d.tif` will be float32. Are there a formats supported by `ffmpeg` which would support float32 natively?

Are you aware of any image format, which would natively support float32 values?
Are you aware of any video format, which would natively support float32 values?

Comment: just checking: you *do* expect video compression to be lossy, right? if you expect lossless compression, then the only benefit to this path is that your video data is actually handled as video data -- best I can think of is various ("raw"/professional) still image formats that are "lifted" into video formats, at least by keeping a directory of lots of individual frames

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am looking for both lossy and lossless. The idea is that individual frames are very corelated so to try some existing video compression algorithm to reduce size or filter data. I did not however found too much information how pixel format conversion is handled. The command mentioned e.g. produces something called yuv420p10le...

Comment: if you're worried about color space conversion messing your data up, you could always store the planes without any conversion. if they're correlated, that can cost some more storage (compression can't exploit it). if not, nothing lost.

Answer (score 0):

[PFM](https://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/PFM/) image format stores still image as 32bit floating point pixels. The format is so simple that it will be easy to write your own code to read/write
PFM files.

Here's an example for creating a sequence of images with float grayscale:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -pix_fmt grayf32le out/processed%05d.pfm
```

Please note you'll need to use `FFmpeg 4.4 or later` to process PFM files.

Another possible option will be `DPX` image format which also supports little-endian 32bit float pixel data.

Comment: Thanks. It actually says Incompatible pixel format 'grayf32le' for codec 'pfm', auto-selecting format 'gbrpf32le', which is still float32 but three channels. More severe problem is to actually find video format or video encoder, which would support float32.

Comment: Have you found a container format that works? I'm also looking for a solution to a similar problem.